# Orderer - Person who Orders

Tags: single-word-requests

This is a simple question - what is the name for a person who orders something?

The word should be 'orderer', but this is incorrect - 'orderer' is not a word.

As an example, I want to buy a product, and I ask my friend to order it for me. I am the buyer, she is the [orderer]?

Comment: But it *is* a valid word - OED: **orderer** *- a person who, or a thing which, orders (in various senses).* It's just that in practice it's not used much (meaningful contexts rarely arise), so it seems a bit strange to many.

Comment: You can just rephrase and use *ordered by* if you don't want to use the uncommon word *orderer*. There isn't any other word but someone who orders something is usually a *customer*.

Comment: Sigh.  The person is acting as your *agent*.

Answer (score 2):

> one who ordered it

Just because we have an idea doesn't mean our language has a word for it.

Just because sticking "er" at the end of some verbs makes them into nouns doesn't mean you can do it to them all.

Just because someone told you that orderer isn't a word doesn't mean it isn't.

> **Orderer** 
>   <sup>[1](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/orderer)</sup>
>
> 1. A person who orders, or who places an order
>
> **Orderer** 
>   <sup>[2](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/orderer)</sup>
>
> 1. someone who places an order to buy
>      buyer, emptor, purchaser, vendee - a person who buys
> 2. an organizer who puts things in order; "Aristotle was a great orderer of ideas"

Just because something actually is a word doesn't mean it sounds good.  People avoid perfectly valid words.  Being right and being in style are two different things.  [Ain't](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/is-aint-a-word) it silly?

Comment: Just because this is just a comment doesn't mean it is a useless one.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like "orderer", (which works fine) you can use "purchaser" or "buyer" in many contexts. Those would emphasize the financial part of the ordering and not the literal act of placing said order.

"Client" or "customer" emphasize the relationship between seller and buyer but only imply the order.

You could be seeking something more emphatically clerical, administrative, or decisive. If so, the list of options keeps growing.